# subscriber not actively receiving published message

Tags: c#, mqtt

I have successfully connected MQTT to my broker both publisher and subscriber are working fine but there is a problem my subscriber is not actively receiving the message, the function mqtt_publishedRecieved triggers only one time,when I restart the subscriber app and only one message receives at a time. in order to get another message, I have to restart my app again. Well, as per my understanding it is because I called the config method of my class at startup. so therefore It checks for the subscribed topic only at startup. But I really want that functionality in my subscriber class to immediately receive the message once it is published by the receiver, which means both should work parallel.
My requirement is
=> if subscriber is connected, receives the message as soon as publisher fires.
=> if the subscriber is disconnected, message should be queued and later on all message will receive when subscriber connected again.

I do a research mqtt clean session set to false will ensure the persistent session so I set that flag to false to occupy persistent session, but it won't work for me.

it seems to me that I should add functionality to receive a message, for example, a button, so when the button is clicked it starts to get a message, but I can't set trigger/callback/button to receive the message for the subscribed topic. My app should start receiving all the published messages when service is started and stopped when it is disconnected.

below is the code of the publisher class.

```
public class publisher : IDatabaseSubscription
    {
public publisher()
        {

                    _mqttClient = new MqttClient("127.0.0.1");
                    _mqttClient.Connect("clientId", null, null, false, 60);
                
              
            }
 private void MQTT_OnChanged(object sender, RecordChangedEventArgs<EventDto> e)
        {
           
                                    if (_mqttClient != null && _mqttClient.IsConnected)
                                    {
                                      var message = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello from app 1");
                                        var statusCode = _mqttClient.Publish("Message1",message , MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_EXACTLY_ONCE, true);
                                        
                                }
                            }
    }
```

below is the code of subscriber class

```
 public class subscriber
    {
        private MqttClient _mqttClient;
        public subscriber()
        {
           
           
        }
        public void configure ()
        {
            _mqttClient = new MqttClient("127.0.0.1");
            _mqttClient.MqttMsgPublishReceived += client_MqttMsgPublishReceived;
            var status = _mqttClient.Subscribe(new string[] { "Message1" }, new byte[] { MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_EXACTLY_ONCE });
            _mqttClient.Connect("clientId", null, null , false, 60) ;
        }

        private void client_MqttMsgPublishReceived(object sender, MqttMsgPublishEventArgs e)
        {
            var message = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Message);
        }
}
```

below is the code in startup

```
if(IsSubscriptionEnabled())
            {
                var service = _container.GetInstance<subscription>();
                service.configure();
            }
```

Comment: It looks like your publisher and subscriber are using the same client id (`clientId`). When a client connects the broker will drop any existing connection with the same client id and I'd suspect that is your issue.

Comment: Hey thank you so much It worked I mistakenly added same client id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was due to the same client id in both publisher and subscriber, broker kicked off the client if the new client connected with the same client id.